# How to identify a user of an application?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, authentication

In my iPhone application, the server needs to identify application user. In a web application, the server can recognize user by cookies. What should I do with apps? A cookie will expire, so I think it doesn't work here. If user can store username and password in the app, she doesn't need enter password every time. Need I transfer username and password EVERY time to fetch data  via https? I think the overhead is really high. Are there alternative methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to another question:

[How to let Rails tell mobile applications that users signed in or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243496/how-to-let-rails-tell-mobile-applications-that-users-signed-in-or-not)

It's a convention to use 'token authentication' with mobile applications.

Answer (score 1):

You could send UUID to server in request. In earlier versions, we could use UDID, but it has been deprecated in iOS 5, so we are preferring UUID.

```
// return a new autoreleased UUID string
- (NSString *)generateUUIDString
{
  // create a new UUID which you own
  CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

  // create a new CFStringRef (toll-free bridged to NSString)
  // that you own
  NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);

  // transfer ownership of the string
  // to the autorelease pool
  [uuidString autorelease];

  // release the UUID
  CFRelease(uuid);

  return uuidString;
}
```

Comment: What if someone else gets this UUID?

Comment: Please check documentation for CFUUIDCreate: 
> UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit values guaranteed to be unique. A UUID is made unique over both space and time by combining a value unique to the computer on which it was generated"

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use an user its MAC address. See this [code](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5/blob/master/Classes/UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.m) on github: